# Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS - Unable to change IPv4 settings duing setup

Tags: networking, server, preinstallation, ipv4

During setup on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS, I have problems setting up manual IPv4.

I'm enter the following:

```
Subnet: 255.255.255.0/24

Address: 192.168.0.50
```

Under address I get the following error:

'192.168.0.50' is not contained in '255.255.255.0/24'

I'm not sure what I've done wrong. I get the same error on two different VMs on two different Networks.

Image: 
[IPv4 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcAAF.jpg)

Comment: That worked @sachin-yadav . Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the subnet use 192.168.1.0/24

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

I thought this was related to subnet mask and not ADDR/PREFIX because of the need to add the /24.